# How to subtract 5 days from a defined date - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script to subtract 5 days from a defined date but seems not working, here's my code:

```js
var End_Day = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 20).getValue();
Logger.log(End_Day);
var End_day_2 = new Date();
End_day_2.setDate(End_Day.getDate()-5);
Logger.log(End_day_2);
```

and the result is not just - 5 days:

```
11:18:47 AM Info    Sat Jun 04 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022
11:18:47 AM Info    Fri Apr 29 11:18:47 GMT+08:00 2022
```

I am quite confused why the date move from Jun to Apr.

Thanks for having a look

Comment: subtract 5 days worth of milliseconds: 60*60*24*5 = 432000 * 1000 = 432000000

Comment: The problem is that you are subtracting 5 days from current date, not from cell value. You need create a date object from cell value, then subtract 5 days from it.

Answer (score 1):

### Try:

```
var End_Day = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 20).getValue();
var End_day_2 = new Date(End_Day.getTime() - (5 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))
Logger.log(End_Day);
Logger.log(End_day_2);
```

### Function:

```
const endDay = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 20).getValue()
const endDay2 = DateFromDaysAgo(endDay, 5)

...

function DateFromDaysAgo(startDate, number) {

  if (typeof startDate === `string`) { startDate = new Date(startDate) }

  return new Date(startDate.getTime() - (number * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what's coming from the sheet is a string, you will have to convert the date string into a date object.

The other thing is you have to work in milliseconds as @vanowm says:

60*60*24*5 = 432000 * 1000 = 432000000

so skipping the sheet entirely:

```
x = new Date
> Fri May 27 2022 11:24:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

y = new Date(x - 432000000)
> Sun May 22 2022 11:24:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: @TheMaster you may be right that getValue returns a date object. I guess it depends on the sheet value format. I just made an assumption there. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to calculate ms either. Just `setDate()` will maintain the previous `ms`.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn more about [Date.prototype.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).It only changes **the day of the month** of a given Date instance.

As the code you posted, the day of the month of `End_Day` is `4`, `End_day_2.setDate(4 - 5)` equals to `End_day_2.setDate(-1)` and the month of `End_day_2` is April according to the console result, because there're 30 days in April, `setDate(-1)` means `setDate(29)`, so you got `Apr 29` at the end. That's how it goes.

One right way to do is substracting 5 days worth of milliseconds.

```js
function addDays(date, days){
  const DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60000;
  return new Date(date.getTime() + days * DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS);
}

console.log(addDays(new Date(), -5).toString()); // 5 days ago
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am quite confused why the date move from Jun to Apr.

It's because you're setting date on today(`End_day_2`) and not on your predefined date(`End_day`).

Change

```
End_day_2.setDate(End_Day.getDate()-5);
```

to

```
End_Day.setDate(End_Day.getDate()-5);
console.info(End_Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Works with any date and can subtract any number of days

```js
const subtractDays = (fromDate, numDays) => {
  if (!(fromDate instanceof Date)) throw 'The first argument must be a date';
  return new Date(new Date().setDate(fromDate.getDate() - +numDays));
};
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Weekago

```
function weekago() {
  let dt = new Date();
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-7);
  Logger.log(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

#### Five days ago

```
function fiveago() {
  let dt = new Date();
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-5)
  Logger.log(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

#### Five days from a date in a spreadsheet cell

```
function fivefromadateinspreadsheet() {
  const v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  let dt = new Date(v);
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-5);//Note that does not return a date it return the numbrer of milliseconds
  Logger.log(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can subtract 5 days from a defined date in Google App Script by using the Utilities.formatDate() method. Here's an example:

```js
function subtractDays() {
  var date = new Date();
  var subtractDays = 5;

  // Subtract 5 days from the current date
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - subtractDays);

  // Format the new date
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  Logger.log(newDate);
}
```

In this example, we first create a Date object to represent the current date. Then, we subtract 5 days from the current date by using the setDate() method. Finally, we format the new date using the Utilities.formatDate() method and log it to the console using the Logger.log() method.

You can modify the subtractDays variable to subtract a different number of days from the date, or you can use a different date object to start with.